# after I press home button ScheduledExecutorService does not run in the background

Tags: android, scheduledexecutorservice

I have created this in onCreate() and after I press home button ; ScheduledExecutorService does not run every 10 mins in the background.Why ?

Where is the mistake.
Please help me out .

Thanks in Advance.

```
        ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable(){

            public void run() {
//play music to check if it executes every 10 mins

                  mp3.start();
            }

    }, 0, 600, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: because your app got killed, I suppose...

Comment: @Leonidos after I hold on Home button and go to recent activities Its there and then the sound is played.

Comment: Where is this executor  code present??? in a service or activity or where? in order to run in background i would recommend using AlarmManager ..

Comment: Its running in activity. How to do the alarm manager. Another thing is if the time is 60 secs then it runs for sometime then it stops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) is more well suited to repeating a task every 10 minutes than Executor is.

I would suggest setting up an AlarmManager and using a BroadCast receiver to "catch" the trigger that it fires, and inside your onReceive() method you can do whatever you like, including start your mp3. I think this way will work better for you, especially if you are intending for you sound to play even if your application is not currently the Active app on the device.

Comment: Thanks .I have a method to run instead of mp3 .Which update data to server will the alarm manager still work in that case.Thanks again Sir.

Comment: yes, but you may want to do the work inside of a service that you start from the broadcast receiver, rather than from the receiver itself.