# scheduleAtFixedRate() doesn't work when the app is in background (and in "release" mode)

Tags: java, android, scheduled-tasks

I'm experiencing a strange behavior on my Android app.
I want to schedule a fixed-rate operation that saves the properties of a "player" object. During the application flow, the user may change it's settings but the saving is performed every 2 minutes by this little task.

The task is run by a static [ScheduledExecutorService](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html), initialized when the app starts:

```
private static ScheduledExecutorService threadExecutor;

//...

public static void initialize() 
{
    if (!initialized) 
    {
        threadExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        // start the thread that will perform a scheduled check for unsaved player state
        threadExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() { 
                // ... the saving operation ...
            }
        }, 0, 120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        initialized = true;
    }
}
```

When I'm in debug mode, this thing works both when the app is in the foreground and in the background too, as espected.
Problems come when I switch to **RELEASE mode**: once the app is in the background (by pressing the home button, for example), this thread stops and the operation is not repeated anymore!

Is there any documentation about this (unexpected?) behavior?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606039/after-i-press-home-button-scheduledexecutorservice-does-not-run-in-the-backgroun suggests to use alarm manager

Comment: ok, is there any drawbacks if I set the Alarm to operate in a such short amount of time rate (2 minutes)?

Comment: I guess there should be no drawbacks. Here is an example of alarm manager that runs every 2 minutes: http://androidexample.com/Create_Repeating_Alarm_Start_After_Each_2_Minutes/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=93&aaid=116

Comment: ok thanks! this should be an answer, not a comment ;)

Comment: and here is one which runs every minute :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8999103/isuues-alarm-manager-in-every-1-min-android

Comment: sure I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html), to run a task every `'x'` minutes.

Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606039/after-i-press-home-button-scheduledexecutorservice-does-not-run-in-the-backgroun) for more information.

And [here](http://androidexample.com/Create_Repeating_Alarm_Start_After_Each_2_Minutes/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=93&aaid=116) is an example of an AlarmManager that runs every 2 minutes.